# Why was getMonth deprecated on java.sql.Date and java.util.Date

Tags: java, scala, date, deprecated, design-decisions

I should preface this with I use Apache Spark, which uses `java.sql.Date`, in case anyone suggests I should use dates from `java.time`. The example below is in Scala.

The API that I use (which is deprecated) to get the month for a date is as follows:

```
val date: java.sql.Date = ???
val month = date.getMonth()
```

However if I look at how it appears I should do this based on the deprecation, the above code would be re-written as follows:

```
val date: java.sql.Date = ???
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.setTime(date)
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

The simplicity and readability of the code is significantly different, and the date being a side effect on the calendar is not terribly nice from a functional programming point of view. Can someone explain why they think this change was made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Prior to JDK 1.1, the class Date had two additional functions. It
> allowed the interpretation of dates as year, month, day, hour, minute,
> and second values. It also allowed the formatting and parsing of date
> strings. Unfortunately, the API for these functions was **not amenable
> to internationalization**. As of JDK 1.1, the Calendar class should be
> used to convert between dates and time fields and the DateFormat class
> should be used to format and parse date strings. The corresponding
> methods in Date are deprecated.

[The JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) explains. Internationalization.

---

"*in case anyone suggests I should use dates from `java.time`*"

There is nothing to stop you from converting to `java.time` classes as soon as possible, performing whatever calculations/modifications you need and, if you need to re-insert, converting back to `java.sql.Date` again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation there! I often do conversions to java.time where it makes things easier, but in some instances having extra objects has negative performance implications (for reference, Apache Spark is a big data processing tool, hence the concern over having to convert objects to different types if not necessary).

Answer (score 2):

```
    val date: java.sql.Date = ???
    val month = date.toLocalDate().getMonthValue()
```

You said it yourself, and I still think: You should use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. When you get an old-fashioned `java.sql.Date` from a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time, convert it to a modern `LocalDate` and enjoy the natural code writing with java.time.

### Why were getMonth() and the other getXxx methods deprecated?

While [Michael has already answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62812296/5772882) with respect to `java.util.Date`, I have something to add when it comes to `java.sql.Date`. For this class the situation is quite a bit worse than what Michael reported.

What is left undeprecated (apprecated?) of `java.util.Date` after the deprecations is that a `Date` is a point in time. `java.sql.Date` on the other hand was never meant to be a point in time. One way to illustrate this fact is that its `toInstant` method — which should convert it to an `Instant`, a point in time — unconditionally throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.  A `java.sql.Date` was meant to be a calendar date to be used with an SQL database and its `date` datatype, which in most cases is also a date, defined by year, month and day of month. Since a `Date` is no longer year, month and day of month, they have virtually deprecated *everything that a `java.sql.Date` was supposed to be*. And they didn’t give us a replacement until with JDBC 4.2 we can exchange `LocalDate` objects with SQL databases.

The observations that lead to deprecation have got very practical consequences. Let’s try this (in Java because it is what I can write):

```
void foo(java.sql.Date sqlDate) {
    System.out.println(sqlDate);
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Samoa")));
    System.out.println(sqlDate.getMonth());
}
```

In one call the method printed:

> ```
> 2020-11-02
> 9
> ```

So we had the 2nd day of the 11th month, and month prints as 9? There are two things going on:

1. Confusingly the month number that `getMonth()` returns is 0-based, so 9 means October.
2. The `Date` is internally represented as a count of milliseconds since the epoch to the start of the day in the default time zone of the JVM. 2020-11-02 00:00:00 in my original time zone (set to Pacific/Kiritimati for this demonstration) is the same point in time as 2020-10-31 23:00:00 in Samoa. Therefore we get October.

You don’t have to change the time zone yourself for this to happen. Situations where it can happen include:

- The default time zone of the JVM can be changed from any part of your program and from any other program running in the same JVM.
- The date may be serialized in a program running in one JVM and deserialized in a different JVM with a different time zone setting.

BTW the first snippet I presented at the top often won’t help against unexpected results in these situations. If things go off track before you convert from `java.sql.Date` to `LocalDate`, the conversion too will give you the wrong date. If you can make it, convert to `LocalDate` *before* anyone messes with the JVM time zone setting and be on the safe side.